# Update value in ACF Field

Tags: wordpress, field, advanced-custom-fields

I have a question. This give me headache for past few days.

I want to create a custom post type using ACF.I have create group field Class in ACF and I also have create custom post type classes.

Things getting complicated when I have another field name course_id in course field group.

In page class, I have make custom post type appear in front end for user to add their class post :

```
/*
Template Name: Create Class
*/
acf_form_head();
get_header();
?>

<?php
global $post;
$post = $_GET['post'];

$courseId = $post;
?> 

<div id="content">
<h4>Title:<?php echo get_the_title($courseId->ID); ?></h4>

<h4>Training Provider: <?php the_author($post->post_author); ?></h4>

  <?php     
     acf_form(array(
          'post_id'   => 'new_post',
          'field_groups' => array(150),
          'post_title'  => false,
          'post_content'  => false,
          'new_post'    => array(
                  'post_type'   => 'classes',
                  'post_status' => 'publish',
                  ),
          'return'    => '%post_url%',
          'submit_value'  => 'Submit',
          //'updated_message'    => 'Course Submit!',
        )); ?>

<label for="classtitle">Course Id:</label><br>
 <input type="text" id="field_5e58c5cd11103" name="acf[field_5e58c5cd11103]" value = "<?php echo $courseId ; ?>" >

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

In class page also I have `$post = $_GET['post'];` that hold post id that pass using url http://localhost/dev6/my-list-course/create-class/?**post=289** and `$courseId = $post;` that hold a value. This value I want to pass/update using ACF field. I want to create class post at the same time update the course id field. For this time I only know how to display the value but to pass the value I am seeking for help to teach or guide me.

Is there any way someone can help me?

Comment: Please include the whole function.

Comment: Hi @HowardE, I have update the question. Basically I only create page create-class.php to display add post acf form at front end